# Change language in universal app in runtime

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to change the language at my universal app at runtime-not when restart the app-,
I tried this code:

```
   private void ArabicRadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!loaded) return;
        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        localSettings.Values["ArabicSelected"] = true;
        Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "ar-EG";
        SettingsHeader.Text = "الاعدادات";
        (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate((Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content.GetType());
        (Window.Current.Content as Frame).GoBack();

    }

    private void EnglishRadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!loaded) return;
        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        localSettings.Values["ArabicSelected"] = false;
        Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en-US";
        SettingsHeader.Text = "Settings";
        (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate((Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content.GetType());
        (Window.Current.Content as Frame).GoBack();


    }
```

the language doesn't change correcty; it changed sometimes and somtimes not.
I don't know what is the reason-This proplem is in both Windows 8.1 and Windows phone 8.1-.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                    Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;
                    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
                    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
                    (Window.Current.Content as Frame).FlowDirection = Windows.UI.Xaml.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
                    var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
```

Also, set flow direction for ar-EG as:

```
(Window.Current.Content as Frame).FlowDirection = Windows.UI.Xaml.FlowDirection.RighttoLeft;
```

For en-us:

```
(Window.Current.Content as Frame).FlowDirection = Windows.UI.Xaml.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..the language changes correctly, But only when restart the app; when i change the language and navigate to other pages the flow direction only changes but language still unchanged but when i restart the app, it works.

Comment: Yes, you need to restart the app to get the changed language.

Comment: Can anybody help me changing the language at runtime?

Comment: Checkout this link: https://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2013/03/26/howto-refresh-languages-winrt-xaml-windows-store.aspx. I was able to reset the language of my Windows store app.